# SSIS - The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data, runs fine in BIDS, not on the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

> The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

I'm getting this error when running an SSIS package from a server job. Normally this is some sort of type error, but I can't see it this time. When I run the package from inside the BIDS environment, it executes successfully.

The package is loading a csv file into a database table. Both executions point at the same file and same database and I have re-uploaded the package to  the server to ensure I am comparing like versions.

What would cause this error to happen when executed on the server, but be fine when run through BIDS?

Comment: From what component are you loading the csv?  Could it have something to do with 32 bit vs 64 bit dll?

Comment: I'm using the flatfile connection. Switching the job step to 32 bit mode hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Same CSV loaded to the same table in the same database using the same SSIS package and it works from BIDS but not SQL Agent? Sounds ... unusual. My triage would look like 1) Run the package on my machine outside of bids (dtexec /file MyPackage.dtsx`) 2) Run the package from my machine against the server copy (`dtexec /ser MyServer /sql MyPackage`). 3) Log on to server and re-run #2 from command line. If all of those work, then I'd look at the second line of output from both and see whether there is a patch level difference between your box and the server.

Comment: Different regional settings between your dev machine and the server? Or the service account and your user?